# Загрузка изображения и вывод его на этой же странице

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Необходимо создать загрузку изображения на страницу и вывести его на эту же страницу (с удалением его из страницы).
сделал загрузку изображения в бд:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Info", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<label for="main-photo">Main Photo</label>
<div class="editor-field">
 <input type="file" name="uploadImage" />
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

в пост методе контроллера сделал загрузку изображения в бд. все работает, но хотелось бы, чтобы при выборе файла изображения оно сразу же отображалось на текущей странице (без обращения к контроллеру). ну и по-хорошему бы еще добавить удаление изображения с текущей страницы.

Как это сделать?

Comment: _"чтобы при выборе файла изображения оно сразу же отображалось на текущей странице"_ -- если можно использовать готовое решение, то см. jQuery-File-Upload -- [тут](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input id="file_image" type="file" />
<a href="#" onclick="preview()">Preview</a>
<img id="preview" style="max-width: 200px" />
<a href="#" onclick="hide()">clear</a>
<a href="#" onclick="send()">send</a>
```

---

```
<script>
function hide() {
    $("#preview").hide();
}
function send() {
    var du = $("#preview").attr("src");   // строка вроде: data:image/gif;base64,R0l...
    alert(du);  // для отправки на сервер заменить на $.post(url, du);
}
function preview() {
    var input = $('#file_image')[0];
    var f = input.files[0];
    if (f.type.match('image.*')) {
        var fr = new FileReader();
        fr.onload = function (e) { $("#preview").attr("src", fr.result).show(); }
        fr.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

По хорошему, для решения данной задачи напрашивается AJAX.

Если переписать под AJAX добавление изображения и добавить его показ и удаление, весь указанный функционал можно реализовать даже без полной перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: я не против сделать это на ajax)) буду премного благодарен за пример или наводку в каком направлении искать.

Comment: @krabcore, наводку я Вам, по сути, уже дал в ответе. Что касается примера. Такой пример за 5 минут не накидать. Особенно под MVC.Так что здесь уже сами. Если что-то не получается, выкладывайте Ваши наработки и задавайте вопросы. Либо ищите или покупайте готовое решение. Ничего личного.